# Is it true that $A \in A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I defined the set $A$ as follow:
\begin{align}
A_0 & =\varnothing \\
A_1 & =\{A_0\}=\{\varnothing\} \\
A_2 & =\{A_1\}=\{\{\varnothing\}\} \\
A_3 & =\{A_2\}=\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\} \\
& {}\ \ \vdots \\
A & =A_\infty= \{\{\{\cdots\{\varnothing\}\cdots\}\}\}
\end{align}

And now this is clear that $A\in A$.

Is there any mistake in my conclusion?

Comment: You did not define the set $A$.

Comment: The symbol for the empty set is `\varnothing`. The Greek letter `\phi` is something unrelated.

Comment: @DanielFischer: $\varnothing$r `\emptyset`

Comment: @tomasz: Is there any way to define the set $A$ correctly?

Comment: Errors like these are often caused by using $\cdots$ (or $\vdots$) without thinking about what it really means.

Comment: I don't think you mean "$A=\bigcup A_i$" - the union of the $A_i$s is $\{\{\}, \{\{\}\}, \{\{\{\}\}\}, . . .\}$ which does not contain itself. For one thing, each element of the union contains at most one element, but the union has infinitely many elements. I think you want to write something like "$A=\lim_{i\rightarrow\omega}A_i$" (which is close to what you wrote initially).

Comment: @2000: As you might have noticed from the many answers, you haven't properly defined $A$. So it makes no sense to ask whether $A\in A$ is true or not.

Comment: @Zhen Lin's comment is worth its weight in gold and should be engraved on the heart of every mathematics student anywhere!

Comment: @AsafKaragila . . . Ouch. Not sure my insurance would cover that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think there are two separate questions here:

- Why does the sequence of sets $\{\}, \{\{\}\}, \{\{\{\}\}\}$, . . . not "approach a limit"?
- Is it possible to have a set $A$ such that $A\in A$?

The second one is more easily dealt with, since it a precise question. The usual axioms of set theory, ZFC, rule out any such set; specifically, the axiom of Foundation (or Regularity) prevents the existence of such sets. However, if we remove the axiom of Foundation from ZFC, then such sets can exist, and there are even set theories - Quine's NF comes to mind, as well as its better-behaved variant NFU - which *require* such sets to exist.

For the former, I think you would find it helpful to try to define in what sense the sequence of sets $\{\}, \{\{\}\}, \{\{\{\}\}\}$, . . . does (in your mind) have a limit, and then try to see what it would take to prove that. Note that there **is** a clear notion of limit for a *monotonic* sequence of sets: e.g., if $\alpha>\beta$ implies $A_\alpha\supset A_\beta$ for $\alpha<\kappa$, then it makes sense to define $$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\kappa}A_\alpha=\bigcup_{\alpha\in\kappa} A_\alpha,$$ and similarly for descending sequences of sets. But your sequence of sets isn't monotonic, so there's no natural notion of what its "limit" should be. And, even if there were, you would need to argue that *properties* of terms of the sequence induce *properties* of the limit, which depends on the properties in question.

Comment: I think there *is* an obvious natural definition of set limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n = A$ if for every $x\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$ there is a natural number $N$ so that for any $n>N$ we have $x\in A_n$ iff $x\in A$. However with that definition, for the sequence in question the limit is the empty set.

Comment: But if there are such sets without regularity, then $ZFC\vdash \neg Regularity$, contradicting the relative consistency $CON(ZFC)\rightarrow CON(ZFC+Regularity)$? 
edit: by "can exist" you mean constructing a model for $ZFC+\exists A\in A$?

Comment: @Ariel: Sets without regularity would of course not be ZFC sets.

Comment: @celtschk Well, sure, but that definition has its own issues - for instance, if $A_n\rightarrow A$ but $A_i=A_j\iff i=j$, then $\lim(\{A_i\})=\emptyset\not=\{\lim (A_i)\}$. Also, it's asymmetric: $X-\lim A_i\not=\lim (X-A_i)$. Whether or not that notion of limit is good depends on what you're using it for.

Comment: @Ariel Um, what? IF we remove Regularity/Foundation from ZFC, THEN the resulting theory has models with sets which are elements of themselves (although not *every* model would have such sets, of course, unless we *add* a new axiom which goes opposite Foundation/Regularity - say, Aczel's anti-foundation axiom). I don't understand how you get "$ZFC\vdash\neg$Regularity" out of this.

Comment: Five posted answers so far, and yet I'm the only one who's up-voted the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Note that for the union definition, both formulas fail, too (indeed, here the precondition is no longer fulfilled for $\{A_i\}$ resp. $X-A_i$). Anyway, why is (for the definition I gave) $X-\lim A_i \ne \lim(X-A_i)$?

Comment: Suppose $X=\{0\}, A_{2k}=\{0\}, A_{2k+1}=\emptyset$. Then $\lim A_i=\emptyset$, so $X-\lim A_i=\{0\}$; but $X-A_i=\emptyset$ whenever $i$ is even, so $\lim(X-A_i)=\emptyset$. Basically, in the definition you give, it's substantially easier to have $x\not\in \lim A_i$ than it is to have $x\in\lim A_i$, and that bias means that the limit doesn't commute with (relative) complementation.

Comment: No, with my definition, the sequence you give does not converge at all. It cannot converge to $\emptyset$ because $0\notin\emptyset$ but there is no $N$ so that for all $n>N$ we have $0\notin A_n$. Note that there's an "iff", not merely an "if".

Comment: Oh, I misread your definition. You're quite right.

Comment: This is equivalent to trying to define a topology on $V$, right?

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to use intuition to define a set. Which is where your problem is.

It almost seems like you want to write something like this,

$$A_0 = \emptyset$$
$$A_n = \{ A_{n - 1} \}$$
$$A = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$$

But what does that limit mean? It needs to be defined itself, and it isn't in your definition.

TLDR: You can't do that! :P

Answer (score 2):

The definition you've given of $A$ is doesn't actually say what $A$ is.  $A$ is presumably supposed to be a *set*.  To say which set it is is to say what things are members of it.  Can you name one thing that is a member of $A$ that you have clearly defined?

There is something somewhat similar to this that is in somewhat standard use: the von Neumann ordinals:
\begin{align}
& \varnothing \\
& \{\varnothing\} \\
& \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\} \\
& \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\} \\
& {}\ \ \ \vdots
\end{align}
The members of each von Neumann ordinal are the previous von Neumann ordinals.

The set of all finite von Neumann ordinals is the smallest infinite von Neumann ordinals $\omega$.  Then $\omega\cup\{\omega\}$ is the next one, called $\omega+1$ (but not called $1+\omega$ since one defines a non-commutative addition on these.  And so on.

The set of all countably infinite von Neumann ordinals us uncountably infinite, and Cantor defined $\aleph_1$ to be its cardinality.  This is not to be confused with $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score -2):

Set theory forbids the existence of a set $A$ such that $A \in A$, as that kind of construction easily leads to paradoxes, such as Russell's paradox.

In ZFC, the axiom of regularity has this immediate consequence.

Comment: This is not true: we can have sets which are elements of themselves without falling victim to Russell's paradox. See for instance the set theory New Foundations. The axioms of ZFC rule such sets out, but this is a consequence of the specific axioms, not a general principle of set theory.

Comment: Or without leaving the ZFC-related theories, there are various Anti-Foundations Axioms (AFA) which assert the existence of various sets, some of which satisfiy $A\in A$.

Comment: The crucial aspect which holds Russell's paradox at bay in ZFC is the use of **Separation** and **Replacement/Collection** in place of unbounded comprehension; in NF, it's **stratification**. In every set theory I'm aware of, foundation/regularity doesn't enter into the equation.